# Redirecionamento incorreto na hospedagem / arquivos

Tags: php, cakephp, cpanel

O site de um cliente começou a dar "pau" uns 3 dias atrás. O site é http://upimob.com.br/ . Quando você entra nele, ele te redireciona para uma **pasta** chamada "index.html" . Pasta essa que nunca foi criada. Já restaurei um backup do dia 05/04/2016, mas ele continua redirecionando para essa pasta. Gostaria de saber se tem como ver aonde ele está fazendo esse redirecionamento.

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.upimob\.com\.br$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/upimob\.com\.br\/" [R=301,L]


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_erros',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
/**
 * Requests collector.
 *
 *  This file collects requests if:
 *  - no mod_rewrite is available or .htaccess files are not supported
 *  - requires App.baseUrl to be uncommented in app/Config/core.php
 *  - app/webroot is not set as a document root.
 *
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * For full copyright and license information, please see the LICENSE.txt
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright     Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link          http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @since         CakePHP(tm) v 0.2.9
 * @license       http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php MIT License
 */

/**
 *  Get CakePHP's root directory
 */
define('APP_DIR', 'app');
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
define('WEBROOT_DIR', 'webroot');
define('WWW_ROOT', ROOT . DS . APP_DIR . DS . WEBROOT_DIR . DS);

/**
 * This only needs to be changed if the "cake" directory is located
 * outside of the distributed structure.
 * Full path to the directory containing "cake". Do not add trailing directory separator
 */
if (!defined('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
    define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', ROOT . DS . 'lib');
}

require APP_DIR . DS . WEBROOT_DIR . DS . 'index.php';
```

Comment: Você tem algum arquivo .htacess no diretório raiz dele? Se sim, abra e poste na pergunta o código.

Comment: @Diego adicionado

Comment: Dentro do ifmodule, coloca isso e reinicia o Apache. Vê se dá certo: RewriteBase /

Comment: Não deu certo amigo. Continua redirecionando.

Comment: Ok, alem da linha anterior, adiciona essa no final, dentro do ifmodule: RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

Comment: Também não deu certo

Comment: Delete o .htacess do diretório public_html e deixe apenas um .htacess no diretório onde se localiza o index, apega tudo que tem no `.htacess` re-upe ele e teste (apenas para testar)